An explicit formula for orthogonal functions
I am interested in orthogonal functions for the inner product
$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \alpha(x) dx$$
where $\alpha$ is a non-negative function.
Given linearly independant functions $f_0, \ldots, f_\ell$, it is possible to orthogonalize this family and obtain orthogonal functions $\phi_k$. Apprently the following representation holds:
$$\phi_n(x) = (D_{n-1}D_n)^{-1/2} D_n(x)$$
where $D_n = |(f_i, f_j)_{0 \leq i,j \leq n}|$ and
$$D_n(x) := \left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
(f_0,f_0) & (f_0,f_1) & \cdots & (f_0,f_n) \\ 
(f_1,f_0) & (f_1,f_1) & \cdots & (f_1,f_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(f_{n-1}, f_0) & (f_{n-1}, f_1) & \cdots & (f_{n-1}, f_n) \\
f_0(x) & f_1(x) & \cdots & f_n(x)
\end{array}
 \right|
$$
This makes me think a bit to Cramer's formula or Gram's determinants, but I don't see the exact relation nor can I prove the formula. Is there an explicit computation or an inductive argument involved?

The formula is obvious. When you calculate the inner product of $\phi_n$ with $f_k$ for $k<n$ you obtain the determinant of the numerical matrix in which two rows will coincide. Therefore it will vanish.

@RyszardSzwarc Thanks for your answer. However, I still don't see how obvious this is: how do you calculate $(\phi_n, f_k)$ here, without anything explicit about the $f_k$?

The notation is slightly misleading. I prefer to use $\Delta_k=\det(f_i,f_j)_{i,j=1}^k.$ Observe that for $k<n$ we have
$$(f_k,D_n) = \left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
(f_0,f_0) & (f_0,f_1) & \cdots & (f_0,f_n) \\ 
(f_1,f_0) & (f_1,f_1) & \cdots & (f_1,f_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(f_{n-1}, f_0) & (f_{n-1}, f_1) & \cdots & (f_{n-1}, f_n) \\
(f_k,f_0) & (f_k,f_1) & \cdots & (f_k,f_n)
\end{array}
 \right|=0
$$
as the row with index $k$ and the last row coincide.  Moreoever $(f_n,D_n)=\Delta_n.$ As $D_k(x)$ is a linear combination of $f_0(x),f_1(x),\ldots , f_k(x)$ we get $(D_k, D_n)$ for $k<n.$ Concerning orthonormality of $\phi_n$ observe that
$$D_n(x)=\Delta_{n-1}f_n(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_kf_k(x)\quad (*)$$ Thus
$$(D_n,D_n)= \Delta_{n-1}(f_n,D_n)=\Delta_{n-1}\Delta_n\quad (**)$$ Hence
$(\phi_n,\phi_n)=1.$
Remark On the way we have used the fact that $\Delta_k>0$ for any $k.$ This can be proved  by induction, along the lines above, as follows. We have $\Delta_0=(f_0,f_0)>0.$ Assume $\Delta_{n-1}>0.$ By $(*)$ we get $D_n \neq 0,$ as the elements $f_i$ are linearly indpendent. Then by $(**)$ we get $\Delta_n>0.$
